# Power BI Dax New Customers, Lost customers, Returning customers and Active customers

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have been banging my head on this for the last few days, I am a newbie to DAX.

I have to calculate New Customers, Lost customers, Returning customers, and Active customers.
New Customers: customers who never made any purchase
If a person has not bought anything in the last 3 months he is considered a lost customer and if he starts again he is a Returning customer. Any person who has bought in the last 3 months is an active customer.

My measures work on a few dimensions for example I can use them to see the evolution of all 4 metrics over time, but I do not get correct numbers on store level and customer characteristics

I tried the cumulative Sum approach to solve this as I can reuse the measures again.

Measure:

```
Total Qty = Sum(sales[Qty])
```

All Months' cumulative

```
Cum Volume = CALCULATE(SUM(sale[Order]), FILTER(ALL(date table), date table [Date]<=MAX(Calendar_lookup[Date])))
```

Last 3 months' cumulative

```
Cum Sum last 3 = CALCULATE (SUM(DateTable[Order]), DATESINPERIOD(Calendar_lookup[Start of Month],MAX(Calendar_lookup[Start of Month]),-3,MONTH))

New Starts =
    VAR FirstTransaction = FILTER(DateTable, CALCULATE([Total Order],ALLEXCEPT(DateTable,DateTable[Customer ID],Calendar_lookup[Date],DateTable[FULL_PRODUCT_NAME])) = CALCULATE([Total Order],ALLEXCEPT(DateTable,DateTable[Customer ID],Calendar_lookup[Date],DateTable[PRODUCT_NAME])))
    RETURN CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(DateTable[Customer ID]),FirstTransaction)

Lost Customers =
    VAR NoTransaction3month = FILTER(All(Sales[Customer ID]),[Cum Sum last 3]=0 && [Cum Sum last 4]<>0)
    RETURN COUNTROWS(NoTransaction3month)

Restart =
    VAR ReactivateTransaction = FILTER(VALUES(Sales[Customer ID]), [Total shipped]=[Cum Sum last 4] && [Total Order]>[Qty])
    RETURN CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Sales[Cust ID]),ReactivateTransaction )

Active Customer =
    VAR ActiveTransaction = FILTER(All(Sales[Customer ID]),[Cum Sum last 3]<>0 )
    RETURN COUNTROWS(ActiveTransaction)
```

Highly appreciates. Thank you

To calculate New Customers, Lost customers, Returning customers, and Active customers.

Comment: Please restate your question and its title in more general terms.